# Rascal Eclipse plugin installation error: "Rascal needs a Java Development Kit (JDK)"

Tags: eclipse, installation, rascal

I am trying to install Rascal, but I get an error while doing so.

I followed the instructions at https://www.rascal-mpl.org/start/

- installed the second latest [Java 1.8 SDK version 191](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)
- installed the latest Eclipse version for windows, 64 bit ([2018-09](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/2018-09/Ra/eclipse-inst-win64.exe)):
- installed Rascal via Help > New Software (using the stable version: https://update.rascal-mpl.org/stable/)

Until here everything appeared to go well.

- After starting Eclipse, I switched to the Rascal Perspective using Window>Perspective>Open Perspective> Other ...>Rascal
- I created a new project called rascal-test

Now the error appears:  [Rascal needs a Java Development Kit (JDK), ...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUYuT.png)

According the Windows-settings a [JDK is installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPgSK.png)

The Eclipse setting shows  [two JRE's (Standard VM).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1Y88.png)

Deinstalling/Re-installing the software and Rebooting the system did not help.

Does anyone have any advice to overcome this error?

Comment: In _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_ add the JDK and remove the JRE.

Comment: That should also work @howlger, depending on where the JDK is installed. We found that editing the eclipse.ini file is the one way that helps most definitely.

Answer (score 0):

It's a configuration issue where Eclipse does not use the right Java installation automatically. You're not the first to run into this one ([throubleshooting](https://www.rascal-mpl.org/help/troubleshooting.html)).

The way to fix it is described [here](https://www.rascal-mpl.org/start/editini.html). It requires locating your `eclipse.ini` file and pointing Eclipse to the JDK. `C:\Program Files\eclipse\eclipse.ini` for windows users, sometimes. Be careful with the spaces and the newlines in that file, because they're pretty sensitive. Also it's a good time to increase stack size and heap memory while you're at it, which is also described [here](https://www.rascal-mpl.org/start/editini.html)

I've included the answer on that page here for easier reference:

- find the file first

  - on MacOSX it may be in
    `/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse.ini`
  - on Windows it may be in `C:\Program Files\eclipse\eclipse.ini`
  - on Linux its where you extracted the eclipse tarball.
- then find the line that starts with `-vm` and add on the next *separate* line
  the path to the java run-time binary, e.g. `/usr/bin/java` or `C:\Program
  Files\Java SDK 1.8\bin\javaw` (note there is no `.exe`).

  - If you can't find the line that starts with `-vm` you should add it before
    the line starting with `-vmargs`
- to have enough memory to run Rascal please

  - set the stacksize using the command line arguments of eclipse `-vmargs -Xss8m`,
  - or you might set this in the `eclipse.ini` file.

    - find the line that starts with `-vmargs` and add on a separate line `-Xss8m`